# Regex to match directory path and ignore filepaths

Tags: regex

I have following input list from which I want to extract directories path and ignore filepaths. Below is an example of input list separated by ;

```
MI4/Search/Service/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml;MI4/Search/Service/src/main/resources/META-INF;MI4/FRSearch/Service/src/main/resources/resource/spring.xml;MI4/Search/Service/src/main/resources/conf;
```

The regex should match

```
MI4/Search/Service/src/main/resources/META-INF;
MI4/Search/Service/src/main/resources/conf;
```

Comment: There are probably better ways to do this.  What platform are you using?  Java? .NET?

Comment: What regex engine or language are you using? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: The above list I am getting from SVN diff..I am loading it to create patch between tags using ant.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, directories can be named with extensions, so checking for the presence or absence of an extension in a path is not a reliable way to do this to determine if something really is a file or directory. In fact, the only way you can determine if a path is a directory or file name would be to use the appropriate OS API, e.g. [`GetFileAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944%28VS.85%29.aspx) on Windows or [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) on Linux.

If this is your requirement, then you should split on the semicolon and iterate over each path that results, feeding each one in turn into the appropriate API to determine if it is a file or directory. If a textual match is all you need, I would still suggest you split on the semicolon and then match each individual path against an appropriate regular expression.

A Ruby function that would extract the extension might look like the following:

```
def get_extension(path)
  path =~ /[^\/](\.[^.\/]*)$/
  $1
end
```

Note that there are a few issues you'll need to deal with. This regular expression, for example, would treat the path `foo/bar/.hidden` as a path *without* an extension. This might not be exactly the behaviour you need. You'd need to tweak the expression appropriately.

You would then obtain all the paths for which `get_extension` returns `nil`. Please let us know which language you're trying to do this in, since there are significant syntactic differences.